# What do "those grand lines in the Greek Tragedy" refer to (St. John Henry Newman quote)?

Tags: catholicism, greek, translation, st-john-henry-newman, pius-ix

In his essay "*The Syllabus*" (which refers to the *Syllabus of Errors* attributable to Pope Bl. Pius IX.), St. John Henry Newman writes:

[image]

The above is taken from pg. 105 of [*Newman's Letter to the Duke of Norfolk*](https://ia904704.us.archive.org/10/items/a678635200newmuoft/a678635200newmuoft.pdf)

QUESTION: What does the line in Greek translates into, and which Greek Tragedy is St. John Newman alluding to?

Here's the OCR of the Greek text (in Unicode UTF-8): οὔπωε τὰν Διὸς ἁρμονίαν θνατῶν παρεξίασι βουλαί.

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ will probably have people who can answer greek questions better, though I'm not 100% sure it belongs on that site

Comment: Actually, the Latin SE accepts this Q since it includes classical Greek, but not NT (Koine) Greek.  See [their Greek policy](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/policy-on-greek-questions).

Comment: @DDS I added an OCR of the Greek text, courtesy of [this tool](https://www.i2ocr.com/free-online-greek-ancient-ocr).  I think you should also try to post this in Literature.SE using their tag [`greek-language`](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek-language?tab=Newest).

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Thank you for your edit and the excellent suggestion. I have posted the question on Lit. SE. See:  https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/25991/on-some-grand-lines-in-a-greek-tragedy. Thanks again.

Comment: @DDS Glad to help.  Learn something new myself.  I'm surprised how quick they respond, and even created 2 new tags just for your Q.  Will keep Lit.SE in mind.  BTW I +1 your Q and +1 the A there as well.  Happy New Year!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more appropriate in Literature.SE and has already been answered there.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Yes; that's a good idea.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Thanks again for all your helpful efforts; and Happy New Year to you as well!